# Update query correction

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership, sql-update, inner-join

What should I change in this query that make the role name of a special username update? By this query after execution, every role name updated!!without considering usernames!! and I don't want that please guide me. thanks

```
UPDATE 
    aspnet_Roles
SET 
    RoleName = @RoleName
FROM 
    aspnet_Membership 
INNER JOIN
    aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId 
INNER JOIN
    aspnet_UsersInRoles ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId 
INNER JOIN
    aspnet_Roles ON aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId = aspnet_Roles.RoleId
WHERE       
    (aspnet_Users.UserName = @UserName)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code calling the query?

Answer (score 0):

It was the membership table and i found the solution . here is :

```
 sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT RoleId FROM  aspnet_Roles where RoleName=@RoleName", sqlconn);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleName", "Reviewer");

                        sqlconn.Open();
                        System.Guid RoleId = ((System.Guid)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());

                        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM  aspnet_Users where UserName=@UserName", sqlconn);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", EditorUserName);
                        System.Guid UserId = ((System.Guid)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());

                        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT RoleId FROM  aspnet_Roles where RoleName=@RoleName", sqlconn);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleName", "ReviewerEditor");
                        System.Guid ReviewerEditorRoleId = ((System.Guid)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());

                        sqlconn.Close();

                        ///  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE  aspnet_UsersInRoles SET RoleId = @RoleId WHERE (UserId= @UserId)", sqlconn);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", ReviewerEditorRoleId);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);
                        sqlconn.Open();
                        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlconn.Close();
```